Zipapp behaviour depends on active environment
I am in environment my_project
My folder structure looks something like this
.
`-- my_project/
    |-- my_app/
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- __main__.py
    |-- setup.py
    |-- README.md
    `-- build.sh

where __init__.py is empty and
__main__.py
def main():
    print('Hello World')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


and
setup.py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="zipapp_demo",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="user1291",
    author_email="yeah,not posting that here",
    description="Some demo app",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[

    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.10',
)

because I have dependencies that rely on extension modules (cf. How do you install a generated openapi client to a zipapp? ) , I want to use shiv to build my app.
So build.sh contains
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

SETUP_EXIT_CODE=$?
if [ $SETUP_EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $SETUP_EXIT_CODE
fi

shiv \
  . \
  -o shiv_app.pyz \
  --root out \
  -e zipapp_demo.__main__:main \
  --site-packages ~/anaconda3/envs/zipapp_demo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/

so far, this works. And the resulting shiv_app.pyz correctly outputs
Hello World

regardless of whether I run it in the my_project environment or activate a base environment before I run it.
Let's slightly tweak __main__.py
from openapi_client import ApiClient, Configuration


def main():
    print('Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

What is open_api_client? Why it's the generated client.
More specifically, I ran openapitools/openapi-generator-cli with a python generator and then installed the output to the environment:
OUT_ABSOLUTE="<path to generated openapi client>"

sudo chown -R "${USER}" "${OUT_ABSOLUTE}"

pip install "${OUT_ABSOLUTE}" --force-reinstall

NOW, if I run ./shiv_app.pyz in the my_project environment (where I installed the generated openapi client), it outputs
Hello World

as it should.
BUT if I run it in a different (e.g. base environment) - which, you know, is the whole point why I'm bothering with all this zipapp stuff ... I instead get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 76, in import_string
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/zip_app_demo/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openapi_client import ApiClient, Configuration
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/openapi_client/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from openapi_client.api.aa_sequences_api import AASequencesApi
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/openapi_client/api/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openapi_client.api.aa_sequences_api import AASequencesApi
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/openapi_client/api/aa_sequences_api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pydantic import validate_call, Field, StrictFloat, StrictStr, StrictInt
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 404, in __getattr__
    module = import_module(module_name, package=package)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user1291/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/pydantic/validate_call_decorator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._internal import _typing_extra, _validate_call
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_validate_call.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pydantic_core
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/out/shiv_app.pyz_407216d2bc06ad19a6a476be4b28081b1673d69730db8ea575cc93921d0ab451/site-packages/pydantic_core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._pydantic_core import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 84, in import_string
AttributeError: module 'zip_app_demo' has no attribute '__main__'. Did you mean: '__name__'?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 253, in bootstrap
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 81, in import_string
  File "/home/user1291/code/my_project/./shiv_app.pyz/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 87, in import_string
ImportError: module 'zip_app_demo' has no attribute '__main__'

so yeah, even switching from zipapp to shiv to bundle my application, I still get the
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'

Which as far as I can tell is actually included in the shiv app. At least once extracted for execution, it shows up:

So my question about this is twofold:

why does the behaviour differ depending on which environment is active?
how do I resolve this and actually build a zipapp that I can execute on my server without having to install additional dependencies to that server?

